# Parsing Twitter feed: -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, twitter

I've resolved an error some of my users were experiencing whenever my app loads JSON from Twitter:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:] unrecognized selector
```

After researching, I believe the problem was the result of using an NSDictionary instead of an NSArray. My question, however, is why would some users with the EXACT same device and iOS version experience the error intermittently? Why wouldn't it either error every time for everyone or never? Does this have to do with memory in use on the device or an interruption in receiving data from the server?

EDIT:

```
//I have since changed statuses to an NSArray
NSDictionary *statuses = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

statuses = [output JSONValue];  

for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{
            Tweets *aTweet = [[Tweets alloc] init];

            //error began (fatal error) on following line
            aTweet.text = [status objectForKey:@"text"];
            aTweet.created_at = [status objectForKey:@"created_at"];
            aTweet.created_date = [dateImporter dateFromString:aTweet.created_at];

            [self.tweets addObject:aTweet];

            aTweet = nil;
 }
```

Comment: Wow... How in Hades could we diagnose code without code?

Comment: Well, I thought the question was a bit more of a general question since I have already solved the error, however, I've added the code

Comment: you didn't post your solution, but i'm going to guess:  you sent that objectForKey to statuses, not status, right?  Xcode autocomplete is the best and worst thing that's ever happened to programming.

Comment: @danh I changed statuses from an NSDictionary to an NSArray as it didn't have any keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where the data in `output` is coming from. You assurme your JSON data is an array of dictionaries, but it's possible that the server is returning something else, for example, if an error has occurred the server might return a dictionary with some error information in it.

You'll have to look at the Twitter API to see what data you might receive for this particular call.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Looking at the page above, you can use the HTTP return code to see if the request has failed, and if that's the case, you can just abort this operation.

Comment: So, for instance, if it received a 503 because the server was busy or an error, it would definitely crash... that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the software is the same but the data is different.

See if you can find out what key was being asked for.

You'll probably find that some records' json have an array at that key (maybe, when there's more than one relation), and some have a dictionary (for a relation with a single object).

I can't think of anywhere in twitter api where that's the case, but it stands to reason.

Comment: Yeah, it was from the same user's feed with no new tweets, however, there could potentially have been a difference in data (maybe a retweet flag, etc)